# Translating Sumifs formula from Excel to Access (2007)

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access-2007, sumifs

I am trying to utilize this Sumifs formula in an Access query, but I am an amateur when it comes to Access.

=SUMIFS(E:E,A:A,A2,B:B,B2,C:C,C2)

Anyone know how to translate this?

Answer (score 0):

You simply add a `SUM` summarization to your query and use the filters to get your desired result.

Comment: Will this summarization work if I need to sum unique combinations?

I am looking at summarizing a 4th column if the first 3 columns are the same, but I have 400,000+ rows of data in Excel and it basically freezes my system when attempting.  Which is my reason for wanting to use Access.

Comment: I figured it out based off your answer, thanks again for your help!

Comment: If it was helpful, please mark it with the gree checkmark.